# Sum and GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone

I have a table with the following fields:

```
public int S_ID       
public DateTime S_Date            
public string S_Month        
public string S_Overtime    
public string S_WorkingTime
```

I would like to `(Orderby S_Date)`, `(GroupBy S_Month)`, `(SUM S_Overtime)`, `(SUM S_Workingtime)` and then I'm using Binding to display it in a ListBox.

The code below works, but it doesn't SUM neither Overtime nor Workingtime

```
var manader = (from c in db.nys
               orderby c.S_Date ascending
               select c).GroupBy(g => g.S_Month).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault());
listBox.ItemsSource = manader;
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what data you have in `S_WorkingTime` and `S_Overtime`, but assume this is a string representation of `int`:

```
var manader = from c in db.nys
              group c by c.S_Month into g
              select new { 
                    Month = g.Key, 
                    Overtimes = g.Sum(x => Int32.Parse(x.S_Overtime)),
                    WorkingTimes = g.Sum(x => Int32.Parse(x.S_WorkingTime)) 
              };
```

BTW I think it makes no sense to order items by `S_Date`, because you group them by `S_Month` and use aggregate values.

Comment: All data in S_WorkingTime and S_Overtime looks like below
02:30 which shows Overtime or 08:30 which shows Workingtime.
There is probably some better ways to get those value but this is what I got.
`DateTime TimeFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(timePicker.Value);
DateTime TimeTo = Convert.ToDateTime(timePicker1.Value);

TimeSpan Worked = TimeFrom - TimeTo;

DateTime work = Convert.ToDateTime(Worked.ToString());

worked = string.Format("{0:HH:mm}", new DateTime(work.Ticks));`

Comment: If it is time range, then why you use `string` as type of property? Use `TimeSpan` instead. And just do `g.Sum(x=> x.S_Overtime)`

Comment: Thanks didn't even think of that... Will give it a try and get back!

Answer (score 1):

```
db.nys.OrderBy(o => o.S_Date)
    .GroupBy(o => o.S_Month)
    .Select(g =>
        new
        {
            Overtime = g.Sum(v => v.S_Overtime),
            Workingtime = g.Sum(v => v.S_Workingtime)
        }
    )
```